# Safari browser audio.play() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari, html5-audio

I am using the following audio tag `<audio id="player"></audio>` and in jquery I have used
`var player = document.getElementById('player'); 
 player.src ='/ajax.php';
 player.play();`

Safari browser showing following error and audio is not playing. `Unhandaled promise Rejection: NotSupportedError: The Operation is not supported`

I have search this but not got any proper solution. Any one knows the solutions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53058421/local-variable-audio-in-object-method-not-playing/53058870?noredirect=1#comment93016882_53058870

Comment: Try adding audiocontext on windowload

Comment: Giving error Can't find the variable: AudioContext. I have used in window load function

Comment: can you console.log your player source? Looks like there is problem with source

Answer (score 1):

The promise's rejection handler is called with an exception name passed in as its sole input parameter (as opposed to a traditional exception being thrown). Possible errors include:

**NotAllowedError**
The user agent (browser) or operating system doesn't allow playback of media in the current context or situation. This may happen, for example, if the browser requires the user to explicitly start media playback by clicking a "play" button.

**NotSupportedError**
The media source (which may be specified as a MediaStream, MediaSource, Blob, or File, for example) doesn't represent a supported media format.

Referenced from MDN website.

As you are getting the `NotSupportedError` error, Your should look for `player.src ='/ajax.php';` here.

Answer (score 0):

The browser had forbidden auto play, users have to click to play.

Comment: Yes I have a play button and after click calling the ajax then we are calling the player.play() function.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Mute settings.

```
  Unmute, if it is set to mute.
  https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21463?locale=en_US
```

Comment: The audio is Unmute.