# javascript audio.play workaround

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for workaound in this subject

```
var sound = document.createElement('audio')
sound.src = "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"
sound.play()
```

it will outputs in an error:

> The play method is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.

is there any workaround for this? libraries like p5.js can play sound without this kind of error, there should be a solution to this problem.

Comment: look the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53058421/local-variable-audio-in-object-method-not-playing

Comment: @erani_246 didn't work, same error

Comment: please try this:
https://plnkr.co/edit/jQkYyrj15eE2oCOgeWQL?p=preview

Comment: @erani_246 well, it worked on that site, but doesnt work when testing locally

Comment: I copied the code to local html file and its working...