# NuxtJS/VueJS: How to know if page was rendered on client-side only?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Currently I create a html5 video player component for an universal nuxtjs/vuejs app.
There is an autoplay attribute for the video tag to start videos after navigate to them.
Usually browsers don't do that directly after page load, it's prohibited.
I need a variable in my component to know if autoplay will be possible to style elements based on this information.
In other words: The variable should be true if the current page was only rendered on client-side, but false if it was rendered on server-side first.

It's not possible to work with "window.history.length" because the autoplay will also not be possible after refresh, although this would not have an effect on the history length.

Also it's not possible to set a variable in the "created" method since it will be called on server- and client-side too.

Comment: perhaps we should see a codesandbox minimal example before proceeding?

Comment: An example is really simple. It's just an default nuxtjs project with a video tag and autoplay attribute.
https://codesandbox.io/s/great-frog-ue5j8?file=/pages/index.vue

If you load the page with firefox, you get this error in the console:
"NotAllowedError: The play method is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission."

The goal is to have a variable to know if it will be possible or not so I can apply the initial styling.

Comment: Lemme check it later

Comment: added explaination of the above error - Firefox requires users to "select play" to play. its to prevent spam websites to autoplay videos

Comment: Yes, obviously. Sorry but the answer is useless. Please comment if you know how to get the information whether the media is playable on initial rendering of the current route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be to get the length of the Vue router entries. This seems currently not to be possible without manually tracking. So I ended with this code in my layout component:

```
watch: {
  $route () {
    Vue.prototype.$navigated = true
  }
}
```

The value of $navigated is undefined or true and so I know in the layout children components if video autoplay is possible or not.

Comment: Nice solution, thanks. Shame about needing to copy paste this to all my layouts (that are potential landing pages for the rest of the site). I have the same issue with an Audio element and autoplay!

Answer (score 12):

In nuxt - there is the `<client-only>` component that renders components only on the client side

```
<template>
  <div>
    <sidebar />
    <client-only placeholder="Loading...">
      <!-- this component will only be rendered on client-side -->
      <comments />
    </client-only>
  </div>
</template>
```

In nuxt, there are is `asyncData` which is run `beforeCreate()`, i.e. you can retrieve data from the server side in `asyncData` before the component is mounted.

[image: nuxt-life-cycle]

Alternatively, you can check on the `created()` for the process, e.g.

```
created() {
  if (process.client) {
    // handle client side
  }
}
```

---

**edit**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53058870/2312051

> Audio.play() returns a Promise which is resolved when playback has been successfully started. Failure to begin playback for any reason, such as permission issues, result in the promise being rejected.

```
const playedPromise = video.play();
if (playedPromise) {
  playedPromise.catch((e) => {
    if (e.name === 'NotAllowedError' ||
        e.name === 'NotSupportedError') {
        //console.log(e.name);
    }
  });
}
```

> In your case, looks like your browser/os does not allow automatic playing of audio. The user agent (browser) or operating system doesn't allow playback of media in the current context or situation. This may happen, for example, if the browser requires the user to explicitly start media playback by clicking a "play" button. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play) is the reference.

Comment: Yes you're right, I didn't think of asyncData. There it should be possible to set the value of process.client in component data. So I can use the state already for the initial rendering.

The problem is that I am on component level and there is no asyncData method.
I want to prevent to cascade the value from page component down to the video component.

Comment: JT2809 lets talk over chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213701/61747371

Comment: Referring to your edit:

It's not possible to wait for the promise. I need the information before. And I could get it like this way:

"The variable should be true if the current page was only render on client-side, but false if it was rendered on server-side first."

Comment: What if it's a node module?