# NuxtJs and VueFlip Integration

Tags: vue.js, plugins, nuxt.js

I am working on a NuxtJs Project and need to use the [VueFlip Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-flip). I first tried to add it directly to my index.vue page using the components like so:

```
import VueFlip from 'vue-flip';
export default {
  components: {
    'vue-flip': VueFlip
  }
}
```

However, in this approach I get an error: `document is not defined`. Which I think suggests that the component needs to be rendered on the client-side. So I tried to add the library as a plugin:
`in ~/plugins/vue-flip.client.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import VueFlip from 'vue-flip'

if (process.client) {
  Vue.use(VueFlip)
}
```

And added this in the `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
...
plugins: [
    '~/plugins/vue-flip.client.js',
  ],
...
```

This approach gives an error in the browser console:

```
Unknown custom element: <vue-flip> - did you register the component correctly?
```

I have also tried using the first approach with  component and got same error.
I don't know how to get the library to work in NuxtJs. Please help.

Comment: The reasonable explanation is that there's no `process.client`. You can debug and make sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61747371/nuxtjs-vuejs-how-to-know-if-page-was-rendered-on-client-side-only

Comment: @EstusFlask even without the if block, i still get the same error.

Comment: Which one? There are two errors in the question.

Comment: the second error.

Comment: You can see in docs that it's not a plugin so it shouldn't be registered with `use`.

Comment: I can see that. That's why my first option was to use it as a component. But I got the "document is not defined" error. And that's why I tried the plugin option

Comment: This depends on how the lib is implemented. If it accesses `document` on import then the whole import needs to be conditional, otherwise only the place where the component is used like shown in the link above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237855/discussion-between-john-graham-and-estus-flask).

Comment: Sorry, I don' use chats, they don't work well with notifications.

Comment: Alright. Can you try out the library with Nuxt and guide me on proper usage?

Comment: I don't have ready to use Nuxt setup at hand to test. The docs already explain how it's done, https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/server-side-rendering/#window-or-document-undefined . A safe way is to import it conditionally with require, because it's sync, while dynamic `import` is not. In your case I'd expect it to be something like 
`if (process.client) { let VueFlip = require ('vue-clip').default;  Vue.component('VueFlip', VueFlip) }`