# nuxt 3 + msal - non_browser_environment error

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

## Introduction

Hello everyone,

I am trying to implement **azure active directory B2c** into my **nuxt 3 application**. Because **@nuxtjs/auth-next** is not yet working for nuxt 3, I am trying to make my own composable that makes use of the **@azure/msal-browser** npm package.

The reason I am writing this article is because it is not working. The code I created can be seen below:

## Error:

**Terminal**
[nitro] [dev] [unhandledRejection] BrowserAuthError: non_browser_environment: Login and token requests are not supported in non-browser environments.     21:07:32
at BrowserAuthError.AuthError [as constructor]

**Browser console**
PerformanceClient.ts:100 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.startPerformanceMeasurement is not a function
at PerformanceClient2.startMeasurement

## Code:

**file: /composables/useAuth.js**

```js
import * as msal from '@azure/msal-browser'

let state = {
    applicationInstance: null,  
}

export const useAuth = () => {
    //config auth
    const msalConfig = {
        auth: {
            clientId: '',
            authority: '',
            knownAuthorities: [``],
            redirectUri: '',
            knownAuthorities: ['']
        },
        cache: {
            cacheLocation: "sessionStorage", // This configures where your cache will be stored
            storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
        },
    }
    state.applicationInstance = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

    return {
        signIn
    }
}

const signIn = () => {
    //handle redirect
    state.applicationInstance
        .addEventCallback(event => {
            if(event.type == "msal:loginSuccess" && event.payload.account)
            {   
                const account = event.payload.account
                state.applicationInstance.setActiveAccount(account)
                console.log(account)
            }
        })

    //handle auth redirect
    state.applicationInstance
        .handleRedirectPromise()
        .then(() => {
            const account = state.applicationInstance.getActiveAccount()
            if(!account) {
                const requestParams = {
                    scopes: ['openid', 'offline_access', 'User.Read'],
                }
                state.applicationInstance.loginRedirect(requestParams)
            }
        })
}
```

**file: index.vue**

```js
<script setup>
const auth = useAuth();
auth.signIn()
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you try to login only in the browser because Nuxt runs also server side.

You can check if you are client side with `process.client` or `process.server` for server side.

```html
<script setup>
if (process.client) {
const auth = useAuth();
auth.signIn() // Try to sign in but only on client.
}
</script>
```

[NuxtJS/VueJS: How to know if page was rendered on client-side only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61747371/nuxtjs-vuejs-how-to-know-if-page-was-rendered-on-client-side-only)

Comment: Hi, thnx for your answer and it indeed helped for my first error, it still gives me a browser console error:  `PerformanceClient.ts:100 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.startPerformanceMeasurement is not a function at PerformanceClient2.startMeasurement` on msal.loginRedirect. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found auth module for Nuxt 3. Maybe it can help you

```
import { NuxtAuthHandler } from '#auth';
import AzureADProvider from 'next-auth/providers/azure-ad';
async function refreshAccessToken(accessToken) {
    try {
        const url = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token`;
        const req = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
            body:
                `grant_type=refresh_token` +
                `&client_secret=${process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET}` +
                `&refresh_token=${accessToken.refreshToken}` +
                `&client_id=${process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID}`,
        });
        const res = await req.json();
        return {
            ...accessToken,
            accessToken: res.access_token,
            accessTokenExpires: Date.now() + res.expires_in * 1000,
            refreshToken: res.refresh_token ?? accessToken.refreshToken, // Fall back to old refresh token
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return {
            ...accessToken,
            error: 'RefreshAccessTokenError',
        };
    }
}
export default NuxtAuthHandler({
    secret: process.env.NUXT_AUTH_SECRET,
    providers: [
        AzureADProvider.default({
            clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET,
            tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID,
            authorization: {
                params: {
                    scope: `offline_access openid profile email ${process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID}/access_as_user`,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, account, profile }) {
            // Persist the access_token in the encrypted JWT.
            if (account && profile) {
                token.accessToken = account.access_token;
                token.accessTokenExpires = account.expires_at * 1000;
                token.refreshToken = account.refresh_token;
            }
            if (Date.now() < token.accessTokenExpires) {
                return token;
            }
            return refreshAccessToken(token);
        },
    },
});
```

Docs - https://sidebase.io/nuxt-auth/recipes/azure-ad-example